# DI for static class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I would like to log errors on my website. Log class needs IHostingEnvironment to get the log file path. DI only works constructor but static class doesn't have constructor.

I removed the static and add constructor but now when i initiate the Log class, constructor is asking IHostingEnvironment parameter. At the end i need to use IHostingEnvironment all my controllers to use log class?

.net Core calls Controller class without parameters from browser. How can i do the same with my log class please?

This is how it is at the moment.

```
public class LogServices
{
    public static void Log(string logMessage, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        string logName = env.WebRootPath + "\\Log\\Log_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy") + ".txt";
        using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(logName))
        {
            w.Write("\r ");
            w.WriteLine($"  :{logMessage}");
        }
    }
 }
```

But I want something like this:

```
public class LogServices
{
    public static void Log(string logMessage,[FromServices] IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        string logName = env.WebRootPath + "\\Log\\Log_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy") + ".txt";
        using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(logName))
        {
            w.Write("\r ");
            w.WriteLine($"  :{logMessage}");
        }
    }
 }
```

If this works, I can just call log file like this

```
  LogServices.Log("Error bal balblaa");
```

But obviously it isn't working because LogServices.Log is asking IHostingEnvironment parameter again. Similar to first one.

Comment: I would suggesting studying some of the documentation. You could get a reference to IHostingEnvironment from your Startup.cs and pass that into your static logger to have a reference. The official documentation probably has a better method though https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a static class. Register your class for injection as a singleton, and ask for `IHostingEnvironment` in the constructor.

```
public class LogServices
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;

    public LogServices(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    public void Log(string logMessage)
    {
        string logName = _env.WebRootPath + "\\Log\\Log_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy") + ".txt";
        using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(logName))
        {
            w.Write("\r ");
            w.WriteLine($"  :{logMessage}");
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddSingleton<LogServices>();
```

Then anywhere you need it, you can ask for `LogServices` in the constructor and it will get injected.

But you can also consider making it inherit from `ILogger` and using the built-in logging framework. You can read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/). The greatest benefit is that whenever you log something, it will write to *every registered logger*, not just one. So it could still write to the debug window, as well as your custom logger, without any extra code.

It is a little more involved though. There is a full example of creating your own logging provider to write to a file [here](https://andrewlock.net/creating-a-rolling-file-logging-provider-for-asp-net-core-2-0/).